# Read data regarding Tennis Tournament. Issue with generalisation of the script

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Sample File and Expected Outcome:**

```
> file_1.txt
A. Aardvark d. C. Capybara
C. Capybara d. B. Badger
C. Capybara d. F. Flamingo
A. Aardvark d. G. Goat
F. Flamingo d. Bye
E. Echidna d. D. Dolphin
A. Aardvark d. E. Echidna

> python spoon.py file_1.txt
No one wins the wooden spoon.
```

---

**Sample File and Expected Outcome:**

```
> file_2.txt
C. Capybara d. A. Aardvark
C. Capybara d. B. Badger
C. Capybara d. F. Flamingo
A. Aardvark d. G. Goat
F. Flamingo d. Bye
E. Echidna d. D. Dolphin
A. Aardvark d. E. Echidna

> python spoon.py file_2.txt
D. Dolphin wins the wooden spoon!

QF: E. Echidna d. D. Dolphin
SF: A. Aardvark d. E. Echidna
F: C. Capybara d. A. Aardvark
```

---

**Information:**

- Write a script which reads the data from file.
- The data consists of the outcome for individual matches held in a
  tennis tournament.
- The data is in a randomised order. The first line containing the
  match does not necessarily mean that it was the very first match that
  was played.
- Use the script to determine who wins the wooden spoon.
- If someone does win the wooden spoon - make sure you print all of the
  matches that were played which determined the outcome of the spoon.

---

**What I Have Done:**

- I figured out how to make lists for each individual "rounds" that
  were played - provided there are three sets of "rounds" in total.
  Meaning: Quarter Final, Semi Final, Final.
- I basically wrote a script which goes through each individual line of
  the data and finds matches where the name of loser (player two) on
  the "line being analysed" does not match the name of the winner
  (player one).
- I use the terms loser and winner, because d. refers to "defeated".
- Once I have created the "three" lists, I then work my way backwards
  using the name of the loser from the final, and finding his/her match
  in the semi final. I then take the loser of that match and find
  his/her match in the quarter final.
- Basically, the loser of that "first" match (in this case quarter
  final) gets the wooden spoon.
- IF the loser of that game is "Bye" then no one gets the wooden spoon.

---

**Issues:**

- My script works great, provided there are only three "rounds" of
  matches.
- If the number of matches increase or decreases beyond the "total of
  three rounds" it does not provide the correct data.
- I would like some help with generalising my solution so that it works
  regardless of the how big or small the data in the file might be.
- Ideally, I would like for the script to go through all of the data
  and figure out everything without me having to code for multiple
  scenarios including one where it might go up to Round #50.

---

**Example Issue Scenario and Expected Outcome:**

```
> file_3.txt
A. Aardvark d. C. Capybara
A. Aardvark d. E. Echidna
C. Capybara d. F. Flamingo

> python spoon.py file_2.txt
F. Flamingo wins the wooden spoon!
SF: C. Capybara d. F. Flamingo
F: A. Aardvark d. C. Capybara
```

---

**Current Outcome:**

```
- Traceback (most recent call last):
-   File "woodenspoon.py", line 56, in <module>
-     winner, loser = final.split(' d. ')
- NameError: name 'final' is not defined
```

---

**My Current Code / Progress:**

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    sys.exit("No file specified")
try:
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    file = open(filename, 'r')
except:
    sys.exit("Could not read file")

outcome = []
for line in file:
    outcome.append(line.strip())

element_index = len(outcome)-1
round_1 = []

for i in range(0, element_index):
    isSame = False
    for d in range(i+1, element_index):
        org_player_1, org_player_2 = outcome[i].split(' d. ')
        comp_player_1, comp_player_2 = outcome[d].split(' d. ')
        if org_player_2 == comp_player_1:
            isSame = True
    if isSame == False:
        round_1.append(outcome[i])

for i in range(len(round_1)):
    try:
        outcome.remove(round_1[i])
    except:
        pass

element_index = len(outcome)
round_2 = []

for i in range(0, element_index):
    isSame = False
    for d in range(i+1, element_index):
        org_player_1, org_player_2 = outcome[i].split(' d. ')
        comp_player_1, comp_player_2 = outcome[d].split(' d. ')
        if org_player_2 == comp_player_1:
            isSame = True
    if isSame == False:
        round_2.append(outcome[i])

for i in range(len(round_2)):
    try:
        outcome.remove(round_2[i])
    except:
        pass

for e in outcome:
    final = e

winner, loser = final.split(' d. ')

for e in round_2:
    if loser in e:
        semifinal = e

winner, loser = semifinal.split(' d. ')

for e in round_1:
    if loser in e:
        quaterfinal = e

winner, loser = quaterfinal.split(' d. ')

if "Bye" in loser:
    print("No one wins the wooden spoon.")
else:
    print("{} wins the wooden spoon!\n".format(loser))
    print("QF: {}".format(quaterfinal))
    print("SF: {}".format(semifinal))
    print("F: {}".format(final))
```

---

**Note:**

- I apologise for the long post / question. I wanted to try and provide
  as much detail as possible.
- I hope that I have not missed any crucial detail regarding the script
  and how it functions, along with what is expected.
- I have a rather basic understanding of Python. I am still learning my way around it.
- Thank you for your time and help. It is greatly appreciated!

Comment: For an *outcome* of `name1 d. name2`, who won?

Comment: One way to generalize would be to write a function that would reduce the data and return a result. then feed the result back into the function to reduce it again and repeat till the result is satisfactory.

Comment: name1 would be the winner from name1 d. name2

Comment: How would I use functions to create, say 50 different lists, and then compare them all - to find the "loser".

Comment: It isn't clear, to me at least, what the *rules* are.  Is the loser the player with the most losses and least wins? In the first example why doesn't Dolphin win the spoon? In the third example, it looks like Flamingo and Echidna tie for the spoon.  Is the program supposed to deduce the order of matches or create an order to justify the result?

Comment: The loser is determined based on the following: 
- The loser of the final game
- The match that was played by the loser, previously.
- The loser from that match
- Repeat all the way to the very first match

Dolphin doesn't win the spoon in the first example because his 'set of opponent' went to win the entire tournament. The spoon determining match would have been F. Flamingo d. Bye - but because it's a BYE no one won the spoon.